# Inserting Postgres serial columns in IntelliJ's table editor

Tags: sql, postgresql, intellij-idea, sequences

I have a Postgres table with a serial column. However, when I try to add a new row, I can't figure out any way to tell IntelliJ's table editor that the 'id' column will be generated from the sequence. If I leave the field empty, it tries to set it to NULL, which of course gives a constraint error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug and it just got fixed.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-92999

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly the same problem with DataGrip 2016.2 and PyCharm 2016.2 Is it only me?